# Excel Formula- Having a number automtically divide in half after 6 months

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm tracking Transitional Housing in a Microsoft Excel- we pay a client's full rent for 6 months, and then half of that for the following 3. Is there a simple excel formula that can automatically half the rent number shown in excel after the 6 month mark?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What have you tried? How is it laid out? This question is missing some details that would make a good answer possible.

Comment: If the rent is in A1, "=A1/2" should do the trick. Or do you mean if the Excel document is literally opened 6 months after the starting date?

Comment: Hi there! Apologies for the lack of detail-as is already pretty clear, I'm new to the Excel world.  Baochan, your suggestion makes sense to me, though wouldn't you need something in the formula to specify what date to half it?

Answer (score 1):

I would put the date of origin of the rent in a column (A), and then the full rent in a column (B).  Then I would put Current Rent in column C, and I would fill the cells in column C with the following formula:

```
=IF(TODAY() > A1+182.5, B1/2, B1)
```

I use 182.5 for half a year.  That way, you get the following:

```
A             B          C
11/19/2013    600        300
11/19/2014    600        600
```

In this case, C represents the amount of rent that you're covering for the client.  If you'd rather have the amount of rent expected from the client, this would work

```
=IF(TODAY() > A3+182.5, B3-(B3/2), B3-B3)
```

In which you get the following:

```
A             B          C
11/19/2013    600        300
11/19/2014    600        0
```

Comment: I just voted Jeeped's solution up.  His is a more useful and elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

From your description you're either paying the full rent (1-6 months), half the rent (7-9 months) or nothing at all (10+ months). You might also want to input future values but have the formula reflect that you are not responsible for the stipend until they actually move in.

[image: Prorated Rental Stipend]

The formula I've used in C2 to calculate the prorated stipend (according to today's date and the date that they moved in) is,

`=$B2*IFERROR(LOOKUP(DATEDIF(A2,TODAY(),"m"),{0,6,9},{1,0.5,0}),0)`

[DATEDIF Worksheet Function](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datedif.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! Forgive my ignorance, but I don't understand how "m"),{0,6,9},{1,0.5,0}),0)" fits into the equation.

Comment: @Nathan - The `DATEDIF` returns the number of months between the *move in* date and `TODAY`. The `LOOKUP` determines how that number  fits into the `{0,6,9}` set and returns the appropriate multiplier from `{1,0.5,0}`. e.g. the rent will be multiplied by either 1, ½ or zero depending upon the number of months. *Move in dates* that are in the future cause an error which is picked by `IFERROR` and translated as zero.